# Python KeyError: '0' on printing a dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

```
File "F:\ake\pa\th\help.py", line 268, in main
print type(outputs[x])
KeyError: '0'
```

My file is quite large, so these are the places `outputs` is seen, in order of how they should be executed:

```
outputs={}

#now in another function
global another_var,outputs

#if malarkey...
elif lines[row][col]=="0":
    outputs["0"]=str(state) #state is either 0 or 1

#back in original function
global outputs

for x in nums:
    print outputs[x], #line 268
```

I really am not sure why I am getting the error above.

Comment: do you strip '\n' from input file lines?

Comment: The traceback is telling you the error occurs on line 268. Can you show that part of the code?

Comment: Exactly. I agree with Daniel what is on, before and after line 268 of your code

Comment: It's a very bad tone to use this many `globals` in Python code. I suggest you to post the whole code on CodeReview.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, any use of global in python is a smell

Comment: @cldy, yes I use `string.replace("\n","")`.

Comment: @Josh, I am very interested into why you think this and how it should be avoided?

Comment: @ACarter, by passing variables to functions and using return values, you can avoid using global at all.

Comment: @ACarter, as I said, can you please paste your code somewhere (StackExchange's CodeReview is a perfect place for that) and leave us a link so that we'd be able to analyze the whole picture, not the pieces of it. And for starter, one can avoid globals by returning values from functions :)

Comment: The probelm is fixed as I said below, but there's no harm in posting it, so I have [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12097/python-keyerror-0-on-printing-a-dictionary-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to tell without minimal code to try to run, but the most likely thing is that your `elif lines[row][col] == "0":` isn't triggering when you expect it to. Print something when you reach there to make sure it is.

Also, do `print outputs` immediately before the error (or, catch the error and print it then) to see exactly what *is* in it. Between those two things, you should see something different to what you're imagining is going on.

Comment: Yup, as you expected. The indentation level was wrong, so it was executing before it should have done. Thanks.